# Target a Specific Child of an Element Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

When I was trying to Target 2nd child using:

```
 $(".well:nth-child(2)").addClass("animated bounce");
```

It was targeting all the children rather than the specific child which i want it to target.

What was the problem with the command?

```
 <script> $(document).ready(function() {
$("#target1").css("color", "red");
$("#target1").prop("disabled", true);
$("#target4").remove();
$("#target2").appendTo("#right-well");
$("#target5").clone().appendTo("#left-well");
$("#target1").parent().css("background-color", "red");
$("#right-well").children().css("color", "orange");

    $(".well:nth-child(2)").addClass("animated bounce");
});
</script>

<!-- Only change code above this line. -->

<div class="container-fluid">
<h3 class="text-primary text-center">jQuery Playground</h3>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <h4>#left-well</h4>
  <div class="well" id="left-well">
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target1">#target1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target2">#target2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target3">#target3</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <h4>#right-well</h4>
  <div class="well" id="right-well">
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target4">#target4</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target5">#target5</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target6">#target6</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Changing the code from:

```
$(".well:nth-child(2)").addClass("animated bounce");
```

to

```
$(".target:nth-child(2)").addClass("animated bounce");
```

I was getting the required job to target only second child done

What was the error in this command

```
$(".well:nth-child(2)").addClass("animated bounce");
```

why is it targeting all the children?

Comment: Use `$(".target:first-child + .target").addClass("animated bounce"); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This will select the second child of any element containing the `.well` class

   `.well :nth-child(2)`
2. Otherwise, this will select any element having the `.well` class & that is the 2nd child of its parent

   `.well:nth-child(2)`

Should use this:

```
$(".well :nth-child(2)").addClass("animated bounce");
```

> note the space `' '` between `.well` & `:nth-child(2)` in the selector

```js
$(".well :nth-child(2)").addClass("animated bounce");

$("#target1").css("color", "red");
$("#target1").prop("disabled", true);
$("#target4").remove();
$("#target2").appendTo("#right-well");
$("#target5").clone().appendTo("#left-well");
$("#target1").parent().css("background-color", "red");
$("#right-well").children().css("color", "orange");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
<h3 class="text-primary text-center">jQuery Playground</h3>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <h4>#left-well</h4>
  <div class="well" id="left-well">
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target1">#target1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target2">#target2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target3">#target3</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <h4>#right-well</h4>
  <div class="well" id="right-well">
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target4">#target4</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target5">#target5</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target6">#target6</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(".target:first-child + .target").addClass("animated bounce");`

```js
$("#target1").css("color", "red");
$("#target1").prop("disabled", true);
$("#target4").remove();
$("#target2").appendTo("#right-well");
$("#target5").clone().appendTo("#left-well");
$("#target1").parent().css("background-color", "red");
$("#right-well").children().css("color", "orange");

    $(".target:first-child + .target").addClass("animated bounce");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Only change code above this line. -->

<div class="container-fluid">
<h3 class="text-primary text-center">jQuery Playground</h3>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <h4>#left-well</h4>
  <div class="well" id="left-well">
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target1">#target1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target2">#target2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target3">#target3</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <h4>#right-well</h4>
  <div class="well" id="right-well">
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target4">#target4</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target5">#target5</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target6">#target6</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He asks for explanation, did your answer explain what happened ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".well:nth-child(2)").addClass("animated bounce");
```

you need a specify child element to target element "target" .

that is right way :

```
 $(".well button.btn.target:nth-child(2)").addClass("animated bounce");
```

Comment: He asks for explanation, did your answer explain what happened ?